# Не работает форма обратной связи на React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, форма, email

Помогите, намучалась с этим, не могу понять где ошибка, сто раз меняла все какое-то время на локал хосте работало, но на сервере нет. Сейчас нигде не работает. Меняла код очень много раз.
Есть сверстанный компонент форма на React.

```
function Cantacts() {
const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
const [message, setMessage] = React.useState("");

let changeName = (event) => setName(event.currentTarget.value);
let changeEmail = (event) => setEmail(event.currentTarget.value);
let changeMessage = (event) => setMessage(event.currentTarget.value);

const form = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post("https://express-js2.herokuapp.com/submit", {
        name,
        email,
        message,
    })
        .then(() => {
            alert("Your message has been send");
        });
};

return (
    <div className={styles.block} id="Contacts">
        <Fade bottom>
            <div className={styles.wrapper}>
                <h2 className={styles.myCantact}>Напишите мне</h2>
                <div className={styles.line}></div>

                <form className={styles.form}>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" onChange={changeName}/>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        size="40px"
                        placeholder="Email"
                        onChange={changeEmail}
                    />
                    <textarea
                        rows="10"
                        cols="60"
                        onChange={changeMessage}
                        placeholder="Your message"
                    />
                </form>
                <button className={styles.send} onClick={form}>
                    Отправить
                </button>
            </div>
        </Fade>
    </div>
);
```

}

Express файл:

```
const app1 = express();
app1.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app1.use(bodyParser.json());

app1.use(cors({
   origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}))
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
service: "gmail",
auth: {
    user: process.env.login, // generated ethereal user
    pass: process.env.password // generated ethereal password
  }
});



app1.post('/', function (req, res) {
res.send('Hello World!');
});
//create andpoint
app1.post('/submit', async function (req, res) {
let { name, email, message } = req.body;


await transporter.sendMail({
    from: 'Toma', // sender address
    to: "docsperj@gmail.com", // list of receivers
    subject: "HR", // Subject line
    // text: "Test gmail", // plain text body
    html: `<b>HR message</b>

<div>
name: ${name}
</div>
<div>
email:${email}
</div>
<div>
message:${message}
</div>`
});

res.send('Submited!');
});
const PORT = 'https://express-js2.herokuapp.com/'

app1.listen(PORT, function () {
console.log('Example app listening on port http://localhost:3000!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

process.env.port

```
const DEFAULT_VALUES={name:'',email:'',message:''}

function Cantacts() {
const [values, setValues] = React.useState(DEFAULT_VALUES);

const onChange = ({target}) => setValues(state=>({...state, [target.name]:target.value}));

const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post("https://express-js2.herokuapp.com/submit", {
        name,
        email,
        message,
    })
        .then(() => {
            alert("Your message has been send");
        });
};

return (
    <div className={styles.block} id="Contacts">
        <Fade bottom>
            <div className={styles.wrapper}>
                <h2 className={styles.myCantact}>Напишите мне</h2>
                <div className={styles.line}></div>

                <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className={styles.form}>
                    <input 
                       type="text" 
                       name="name"
                       value={values.name}
                       placeholder="Name" 
                       onChange={onChange}
                    />
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        size="40px"
                        name="email"
                        value={values.email}
                        placeholder="Email"
                        onChange={onChange}
                    />
                    <textarea
                        rows="10"
                        cols="60"
                        name="message"
                        value={values.message}
                        onChange={onChange}
                        placeholder="Your message"
                    />
                    <button className={styles.send} >
                       Отправить
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </Fade>
    </div>);
}
```

Express файл:

```
const app1 = express();
app1.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app1.use(bodyParser.json());

app1.use(cors({
   origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}))
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
service: "gmail",
auth: {
    user: process.env.login, // generated ethereal user
    pass: process.env.password // generated ethereal password
  }
});



app1.post('/', function (req, res) {
res.send('Hello World!');
});
//create andpoint
app1.post('/submit', async function (req, res) {
let { name, email, message } = req.body;


await transporter.sendMail({
    from: 'Toma', // sender address
    to: "docsperj@gmail.com", // list of receivers
    subject: "HR", // Subject line
    // text: "Test gmail", // plain text body
    html: `<b>HR message</b>

<div>
name: ${name}
</div>
<div>
email:${email}
</div>
<div>
message:${message}
</div>`
});

res.send('Submited!');
});
const PORT = process.env.port || 3000; // this line was changed

app1.listen(PORT, function () {
console.log('Example app listening on port http://localhost:3000!');
});
```